# Samba share from Linux host to VirtualBox client requires restart

Tags: linux, virtualbox, samba

I have a Linux host and a Windows 10 VirtualBox guest. I use samba to share a folder from the host to the client over the vboxnet0 interface which is a Host-only adapter.

Samba version: 4.11.6-Ubuntu

Samba config:

```
interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0 vboxnet0
bind interfaces only = yes
```

This is working fine but only after I restart samba after starting the virtual guest. This seems to be because the vboxnet0 interface is not created until I start my virtual guest so samba will not bind to it until after the restart which requires root privileges.

Is there a way to have this work without the manual samba restart?

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox interface gets created with the IP on boot when the Virtualbox
drivers are loaded. What happens after to break this is something on the
host side.

Your described symptom might indicate that this happens when Network Manager
takes control of vboxnet afterward.

Check your `/var/log/messages` and check for your Linux on how to disable
Network Manager control of vboxnet.

Another possibility is to create the interface manually by adding to
`/etc/rc.d/rc.local` a command such as:

```
VBoxManage hostonlyif create >/dev/null 2>&1
```